# In Java netbeans init(); method is used, what is the purpose of it?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have started work on `JFrame` in Netbeans. Actually, I do not have knowledge that Why this `init()` Function/Method is use in `JFrame`? What is the purpose of it? 
Please Explain me about it.

Thanks,

Comment: What `init` method are you talking about?

Comment: What would any init() method be used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Netbeans GUI Builder tool, I think the method you are referring to is the `initComponents();` method call that you see in your constructor.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

If you look below the constructor you will see

[image]

If you look closely, you will see a `+` next to line 31. You can expand that code region by pressing the `+`. When you do, you will see the auto-generated `initComponents()` method that is called in your constructor.

[image]

If you look through the method, you will see that's where all of your components are initialized, and the laying out of the components is done.